# Redirect http to https for certain path on an Nginx site

Tags: nginx

How do you redirect certain paths on an Nginx-hosted site from http to https?

I want to ensure everyone visiting the path "/admin" is behind https. Googling finds me [several guides](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/useful-rewrites-for-nginx) about how to add global rewrite rules, but I can't find anything about how to add a rewrite rule for a specific site.

All the examples I see for doing this use the `server{}` syntax, which isn't allowed in a site's configuration file. What's the site-specific syntax equivalent?

I have a load balancer that accepts 443 connections, does all the SSL handling, and forwards requests to my server on port 80, do Nginx doesn't actually need to serve requests on port 443. It just needs to see that requests are originally coming from http and redirect the user to https. Previously, I was doing this redirect in Apache using a rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

What's the equivalent in Nginx?

Comment: Why are you not running the whole website on https?

Comment: Indeed, there are quite a few attacks one can make against your users because you don't run the entire website on https. Having https on only part of the site was never really a good idea; it's absolutely critical that you don't do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent configuration in Nginx is...

`if ( $x-forwarded-proto != 'https' )
  return https://$host$request_uri;
}`

Please be aware that "[using if is not evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)" if used correctly.

> How do you redirect certain paths on an Nginx-hosted site from http to
>   https?

`location /pathtoredirect {
  return https://$host$request_uri;
}`

So, for your particular situation, the solution would go something like this...

```
location /admin {
  if ( $x-forwarded-proto != 'https' )
    return https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # directives to process /admin when accessed via https
  # ...
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Generally in Nginx you [avoid "if" statements where possible](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Comment: The link is already mentioned in the answer, with a note on it.

Comment: Suggest that the if statement is not needed since the location block should be within the http location block. Of course if one location block serves both http and https (which I don't do personally) then you have little choice but to use if.

Comment: @Tim You have little choice when nginx is behind a load balancer that terminates TLS, as the original post stated.